# how to get sql statement with tshark?

Tags: mysql, wireshark, tshark

I have read the user guide carefully and using the command below to get the sql statement on my local macbook.

```
tshark  -Y mysql.query -T fields -e mysql.query
```

I have installed mysql locally and run it at port 3306. I have tried the command on Loopback and en0(Wi-Fi).

After I ran the command above I didn't get any output. So I just capture the packet on port 3306, using the command:

```
tshark -f 'tcp src port 3306 or tcp dst port 3306'
```

However ,I still can't get any packet at port 3306, though I have ran many sqls such as:

```
select * from wanshao_src;
show databases;
insert into wanshao_src(name,age) values('Jack',18).
```

I am using mysql 5.7.20.

Do I miss some important point during my test?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect to a remote db server and execute some sql, then the command works.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the Wireshark to the latest version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32178552)